# Xamarin.Forms: Extend CommonToolbarPage class with all pages

Tags: inheritance, xamarin, xamarin.forms, toolbaritems

I am developing `ToolbarItem` in xamarin forms app. I need to have `ToolbarItem` throughout the app. For doing so I have created `CommonToolbarPage` class and extending with `ContentPage` to use in all pages. But `Main.xaml.cs` page is inherites with `TabbedPage`. How can I use `CommonToolbarPage` with main page.
Below CommonToolbarPage class code

```
public class CommonToolbarPage : ContentPage    
{
    public CommonToolbarPage()
        : base()
    {
        Init();
    }
    private void Init()
    {
        this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem() { Icon="kid", Priority = 0, Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary });
        this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem() { Text = "License", Priority = 0, Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary });           
    }
}
```

And below is `Mainpage.xaml.cs` class

```
 public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
        {
            public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
        }
```

Mainpage.xaml here look at `Mykid`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CustomPages:CommonToolbarPage2  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TabbedApp.MainPage"
             xmlns:CustomPages="clr-namespace:TabbedApp.CustomPages;assembly=TabbedApp"   
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedApp">
    <local:DairyTabs Icon="dairy" HeightRequest="10" WidthRequest="10" ></local:DairyTabs>
    <local:Mykid Icon="kid" ></local:Mykid>
    <local:Event Icon="about"></local:Event>
</CustomPages:CommonToolbarPage2>
```

How can I use CommonToolbarPage with Main.xaml.cs page

```
public partial class MainPage : CommonToolbarPage2
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

DiaryTab.xaml.cs(First tab first page)

```
namespace TabbedApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class DairyTabs : ContentPage
    {
        public DairyTabs()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            btnDemo.Clicked += delegate
            {
                CreateTabs();      
            };
        }
        private async void CreateTabs()
        {
            TabbedPage tp = new TabbedPage();
            tp.Children.Add(new ChildPage());
            tp.Children.Add(new Mykid());
            tp.Children.Add(new Event());          
            await Navigation.PushAsync(tp,false);   
     }

    }
}
```

When I am clicking on *Go for 2nd page* button getting below output without toolbarItem(If I am not inheriting all page file cycle pages)
See below screenshot

[image]

Comment: Main page should be a TabbedPage ? if not juste change it to a content page

Comment: Let's say, if  `Mainpage2.xaml.cs` is tabbed page even than i will be facing issue. Why because along with tabs(or every page) I need `ToolbarItem`.

Comment: `TabbedPage` inherits from `MultiPage<Page>` and `ContentPage` from `Page`. You can try adding code ineheriting from page

Comment: See my updated question, when inheriting `CommonToolbarPage` class from `Page` class getting above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking to this thread on Xamarin Forum : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/97340/create-toolbaritems-using-template-or-some-other-dynamic-mechanism

Your code seems to be totaly legal. But looking for the renderer `TabbedPage`, You can't inherit for `ContentPage` and apply it to a TabbedPage`.
You should create a new base class for this kind of pages :

```
public class CommonToolbarPage : TabbedPage
    {
        public CommonToolbarPage()
            : base()
        {
            Init();
        }

        private void Init()
        {
            this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem() { Text = "Help", Priority = 0, Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary});
            this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem() { Text = "License", Priority = 0, Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary });
            this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem() { Text = "About", Priority = 0, Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary });
        }

    }
```

If you are using **MVVM** and not **CodeBehing** development method, you can bing the Toolbar Item property, the **XAML** look like this :

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem1" Order="Primary" Icon="Microsoft.png" Text="Item 1" Priority="0" />
    <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem2" Order="Primary" Icon="Xamarin.png" Text="Item 2" Priority="1" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Instead of setting the Items staticly, you will have a base view model that will create the items in the constructor.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Your suggestion is worth implementing. Still I am facing 1 issue. When I go to 2nd tab, Page is `Mykid.xaml.cs` inheriting from `Contentpage` toolbar, It is showing 4 tabs. 2 from Mainpage & other 2 from same page(`CommonToolbarPage : ContentPage`). See my updated question to be more precise.

Comment: It's normal, Tabbed page is the same page and you do not call all lifecycle page. So only the tabbed page need the item in your case. Not the child page consumed by the tabbed page

Comment: If I am not irritating you :). If I won't extend toolbar with all life cycle pages I am facing another issue. Please see my update question for more clarification. if you need any clarification can me regarding above changes

Comment: Hummm, have a look to this thread. Seems that onappearing is called twice in tabbed page : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/72673/tabbed-chlid-page-onapearing-invoking-twice

Comment: Still I am not getting how to solve this issue. Why because even I am not overriding `OnAppearing`. If I override what code I will write there.